# Prove the limit evaluates to $1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x, y) = \frac{\mid x\mid}{\mid x\mid + \space y^2}$ for $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$. Show that $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, mx) = 1, \space \forall m \in \mathbb{R}$$

So $f(x, mx) = \frac{\mid x\mid}{\mid x\mid + \space m^2x^2}$

So $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, mx) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\mid x\mid}{\mid x\mid + \space m^2x^2}$$

Consider the left side, $x \to -x$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x}{-x + m^2x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x}{x(mx - 1)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-1}{mx - 1}$$

But isn't that equal to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{-x}{x(m^2x-1)}=\frac{-1}{m^2x-1}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\frac{-1}{0-1}=1$$

Comment: I was thinking infinity so I got the horizontal asymptote! Thanks sir

Comment: @Amad27 Any time.

Answer (score 1):

Typo: you need $m^2$ instead of $m$ in the last two expressions:

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x}{-x + m^2x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x}{x(\color{red}{m^2}x - 1)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-1}{\color{red}{m^2}x - 1}$$
>
> But isn't that equal to $0$?

No, since:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-1}{m^2x - 1} = \frac{-1}{m^2\cdot 0 - 1} = \frac{-1}{-1}=1$$